# How to reduce the CPU utilization when google and bing crawls on magento site?

Tags: php, magento, amazon-web-services, nginx, magento-1.9.1

I have been facing a weird situation for a while now and need a guidance regarding this.

**Problem:**
*Since last two days we were experiencing very slow website as compared to what it was when we launched the server . We thought it was temperory issue . But now , it has gone dead slow & a page takes atleast 3 mins to load. I also checked that the CPU uitlization somehow reached 100% and believe that the crawling might doing this.*

We are using some third party to do our SEO and google dynamic remarketing and advertising of our magento website. i firmly believe that these things needs to crawl my website for indexing over the search engine.

I have seen that google and bing crawls our website regularly. You may call it google bot and bing bot and suddenly it has seen a largest spike.

**Have a look at the screenshot:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c4u04rhtbi99j0/Screenshot%202015-11-14%2014.16.41.png?dl=0

With the largest spike being caused by bing and google at the same time and the smaller ones appear to only be google bot.

So i just had a quick question regarding this?

*Do you guys think that if a bot IP is whitelisted, will we have a problem with the SEO and google advertising and dynamic remarketing, because then it will not allow that IP to crawl on our website???*

*Is this a spam or the bots crawling our store which is causing store response time to reduce which can impact search engine ranking and conversions on our store??*

*Can a large instance type of AWS will help us solving our CPU-usage problem??*
**Note**: We are already using **m3.large** instance type.

Comment: The problem with search engines is that they crawl everything, which essentially means a denial of service attack on your site. You could implement a CDN like CloudFlare (cheaper) or Akamai (expensive) which could take some of the load off. If you're already on AWS then CloudFront may be a good option too...

Comment: Ok, will use cloudfront and then see, but can you let me know how Cloudfront can help if we load css, js n media, skin folders on it.  I know some basics, though I m not that expert in SysOps of AWS not that good in system administration..

Comment: From the other side make sure server is well configured (caching layer, php, Nginx, database, file system). So to help you with that post the config files with logs here please. Caching layer within Nginx may significantly reduce load on the database and file system.

Answer (score 0):

*Is this a spam or the bots crawling our store which is causing store response time to reduce which can impact search engine ranking and conversions on our store??*

Bots and crawlers can cause a sustainable traffic and resource spike for a single magento server. Regardless of what's in place to speed up magento's performance like: magento's default caching, nginx or apache settings, installed extensions etc...

*Can a large instance type of AWS will help us solving our CPU-usage problem?? Note: We are already using m3.large instance type.*

Absolutely -- a Burstable t2.large instance can be more cost effective and could better handle traffic spikes like those caused by bots. So long as you have a semi-predictable traffic pattern. Like higher traffic during the day and lower overnight, the instance will gain credits that it can use to burst above normal CPU capacity see this for a thorough explanation:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/low-cost-burstable-ec2-instances/

The biggest help I saw was having a properly configured robots.txt for magento  It makes sure crawlers are directed to the right places making sure your server only has to serve up only the pages it needs to.  This post is a great place to start:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14891/how-do-i-configure-robots-txt-in-magento

In Google and Bing's webmaster tool once you verify your domain you can change the crawl rate if necessary.

You can also implement a referral spam blocking with Nginx see:

https://github.com/Stevie-Ray/referrer-spam-blocker